# Rails send_data to csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a method in a module which generates a csv file called to_csv.

My controller action:

```
def download_csv
    @rating = RatingSet.find(params[:rating_set_id])
    rating_id = @rating.id
     respond_to do |format|
                format.csv { send_data @rating.to_cvs(rating_id) }
  end
end
```

My route:

```
download_csv_co_view_rating_index GET  /co_view_rating/download_csv(.:format)     co_view_rating#download_csv
```

My view:

```
<small><%=link_to "Download CSV Data", :controller => "co_view_rating", :action => "download_csv", :rating_set_id => rating.id %></small>
```

When I click the link, the link will open:

> co_view_rating/download_csv?rating_set_id=6

But nothing happens. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Note the typo: `send_data @rating.to_cvs(rating_id)`, you have `to_cvs`, did you mean `csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the format type to your link_to helper:

```
<%= link_to "Download CSV Data", url_path(:format => :csv), ... %>
```

#### Update

If you need to include the params as well then do:

```
<%= link_to "Download CSV Data", url_path(params.merge(format: "csv")), ... %>
```